# Missing namespace or assembly in Razor syntax when using ViewBag, but fine with Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses the Entity Framework and has a Class Library project with methods that return `ObjectSet<T>` instances.

I've got a Controller that has code like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var students = context.GetStudents();

    return View(students);
}
```

Here, GetStudents returns a type of `System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<Student>`.

In my view I have the code `@Model.Count()`, which correctly displays the number of items in the model. This works wonderfully.

What's odd is that if I change the action so that it puts `students` in `ViewBag` then I start getting errors. Specifically, if I do:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var students = context.GetStudents();

    ViewBag.Students = students;

    return View(students);
}
```

And then add `@ViewBag.Students.Count()` in my view I get a Yellow Screen of Death with the following message: "'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'Count'"

Why does it work (as expected) with the model but not with `ViewBag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewBag uses new .NET 4.0 dynamic feature. Your code doesn't work for the exact same reason for which the following code doesn't work:

```
IEnumerable<int> array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
dynamic foo = array;
Console.WriteLine(foo.Count());
```

Extension methods cannot be resolved on dynamic objects. You can make it work by the following monstrosity:

```
 @(((System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<Student>)Model).Count())
```

But please promise me you will never do anything like this.

The fact that your code doesn't work is actually a good thing. Because IMHO what you are trying to do is wrong in many aspects:

1. You are passing domain models to your views instead of using view models.
2. You are passing data access specific objects to your view such as `ObjectSet<T>` instead of using plain CLR objects.
3. You are using a weakly typed ViewBag => you are loosing Intellisense, you will need to perform some casts in your views in order to invoke certain overloads of some helper methods (which would lead into spaghetti code), you get some cryptic errors because of the dynamic nature of ViewBag, you name it, ...

So the correct way to do this would be to define a view model which will contain only the properties that your view cares about. For example:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller action would query the repository and fetch a model which will be mapped to a view model passed to the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = context.GetStudents();
    var viewModel = model.Select(x => new StudentViewModel
    {
        Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)
    }).ToArray();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and finally your strongly typed view would only depend on the specific view model (a view shouldn't care about data access specific stuff, it should only be passed whatever it needs to show):

```
@model StudentViewModel[]
<div>We have @Model.Length students</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I do use the techniques you suggest in most of my projects, this is one for a client who has an existing app and just needs me to fix one particular issue on this view. Unfortunately, he doesn't have the budget to have me refactor the framework to use view models, POCO DTOs, etc.

Comment: @Scott Mitchell, well, it's up to you. Personally when I see some code like this I explain the client that he is doing MVC the wrong way and that one of the reasons why he migrated from classic WebForms to MVC was to have clean code and proper code and that if he continues in that direction one day it would cost he much more to re-engineer the application, because you know, the more crap you add, the more time you would need later to clean it. I explain him that it would be better to invest a little more today and capitalize in the future.

Comment: I agree, and that's how I explain it to the client. But most of my clients are small businesses with tight budgets. This one in particular is in a field that was hit hard over the past couple of years with the budget problems of the state he lives in, as the state is a major source of revenue for his company. In short, for this guy, it boils down to: do something today or do nothing today and wait for greener pastures.